# Helm chart and DC wise

Tags: kubernetes-helm

We have helm chart handy and working in the "lab" which is not production. Now coming to production, we have (say) 3 regions = USA, CAN, FRA kubernetes. The worker nodes in 3 regions kubernetes do carry DNS for example "acme001.example.usa.com" and "acme001.example.can.com" and "acme001.example.fra.com", these worker nodes were registered with controlplane/etcdl/master k8s API.

Question mark - using helm chart say we run `helmfile -e prod apply` will only deploy to production k8s which have mixed up region wise DNS worker nodes. How do we identify "usa" or "fra" or "can" as we have use-case to assign specific passwords.

Something using `{{- if eq .Values.myApp.region "usa" }}` in  deployment template, so that we can use the region in the the worker node FQDN (by means of using `fieldPath: spec.nodeName`) , how do we extract/retrieve "usa" or "fra" or "can" from "spec.nodeName" so that the appropriate values can be assigned in order to pass the values (configmap) accordingly  ? Yes we can use "helpers.tpl" to pass, my doubt is how can we extract region from nodeName.

Comment: You can't see the `nodeName` value at deploy time; your Deployment won't have created Pods that can be scheduled.  You mention using Helmfile, can you pass or compute the value at the Helmfile layer?  What value are you actually trying to set?  Can you [edit] the question to include an example of what your chart looks like?